# nodes and topics -like i'm 5

Tags: ros, beginner, node, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing the ROS beginner tutorials and am on the 'understanding nodes' one. What actually is a topic? I see that a node is essentially an executable file and they communicate w eachother using topics but what is a topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269466/nodes-and-topics--like-i%27m-5/) by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2017-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A topic is the way nodes communicate with each other. Think of it like a newsletter--the terminology for topics is exactly the same.

Say you have a node that generates images, and it wants to send them to other nodes. The node *advertises* that it is going to publish `sensor_msgs/Image` messages on a *topic*. The topic has a URI, which is a path like `/image` or `/vision/image` (it can be whatever you want it to be). The ROS master keeps track of what nodes have advertised what topics.

Now say you have another node that processes images, and it wants to get them from the other node. This node *subscribes* to `sensor_msgs/Image` messages on the same topic.

The ROS master sees the publisher and the subscriber, and it tells the nodes how to connect directly. Now, whenever the first node publishes an image, it gets sent (over a TCP socket) to the subscribing node. A topic can have any number of publishers and any number of subscribers; every subscriber gets every message from every publisher.

Any questions?

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-24**:
Perhaps to make it more explicit: a topic is essentially nothing more than a name (or an address). It is not a magic entity that is actually, concretely involved in the exchange of msgs, but is only used to bring producer and consumer together.

After that they will exchange information directly, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-24**:
.. without caring about the topic or the master.

And also note that using topics (alone) is just one such way to implement a communication system such as ROS. There are also *type based* systems (where you get all msgs of a certain type (say the `sensor_msgs/Image` that @Ed Venator mentions)) ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-24**:
.. and *content based* systems (in which you express interest in msgs that have a certain contents, with a filter expression fi (ie: I want all msgs that have a field called `field0` with a value `464`)).

**Comment by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on 2017-08-24**:
thank you, helpfull

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-25**:
If this answered your question, then you should mark it as correct.